# how to implement sample jms, springs program in my eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, jms, myeclipse

I'm new to jms and springs and eclipse as well. i'm trying to implement jms example using Springs in MyEclipse 7.1, and i have been referring the following url.

http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/12/implementing-jms-with-spring-messaging.html

But Iam unable to understand how to execute the program, it contains a servlet but does not have any html or jsp page, should i create a web project for it or java application? How do i run the program.

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide any tutorial for jms with springs in Myeclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a web project to hold the servlet. A web project will have a directory for java source and a directory for web content (images, html, jsp, etc.). Make sure that you put the servlet code inside the java source directory. You will also need to register the servlet in web.xml unless it is a Java EE 5 servlet with annotations.

To run your servlet, right click on it and select Run As -> Run on Server

Comment: okay but when i run the project, since its a web project wont it look for an jsp or html page such as index.jsp...

Comment: This is the error i get when i try to run on server."There are no configured servers that support the applications deployment type"  I've Myeclipse tomcat running. Other web apps run correctly